# Redirection in promise for React JS

Tags: reactjs, redirect, promise

I'm looking to redirect into a promise when it's in the'then'. But it doesn't work with `history.push()` and `Redirect` either. Is there another way to do it?

Here is the function:

```
let submit = (e: any) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (userData.password === confirmPassword) {
            userService.postRegister(userData)
                .then(function (data) {
                    store.addNotification({
                        title: "Succès",
                        message: "Votre inscription a été prise en compte",
                        insert:'top',
                        type: 'success',
                        container: 'top-right',
                        animationIn: ["animated", "fadeIn"],
                        animationOut: ["animated", "fadeOut"],
                        dismiss: {
                            duration: 5000,
                        }

                    })
                    console.log("test");
                    history.push("/signin");
                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                    store.addNotification({
                        title: "Erreur",
                        message: "L'inscription n'a pas pu aboutir",
                        insert:'top',
                        type: 'danger',
                        container: 'top-right',
                        animationIn: ["animated", "fadeIn"],
                        animationOut: ["animated", "fadeOut"],
                        dismiss: {
                            duration: 5000,
                        }
                    })
                });
```

Comment: HI, could you post the full component source?
Don't you get any error when you do ```history.push("/signin");```

Comment: [https://pastebin.com/VanDX9Di]  And i have any error with `history.push("/signin")`

Comment: Have you defined your routes?

Comment: Yes i do, i have define my routes

Comment: I think you have to make you function async because of history.push()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked your full code and it's really wrong.

Please create a file "useRouter.js"

```
import {useContext} from 'react'
import {__RouterContext} from 'react-router'

export default () => useContext(__RouterContext);
```

On your formsignup file,
please remove all related to history first.

and insert the following

```
import useRouter from 'path to useRouter.js'

...

function SignUpForm(props: any) {
...
const router = useRouter()

...
router.history.push('/signin'); // write this where you want to push
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try

```
let submit = async (e: any) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

@tareq

This changes the route to "http://localhost:3000/signup#/signin" but stays on the page in question.

These are the roads in question:
App.tsx render function

```
render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="App">
                    <Header/>>
                </div>

                <div className="App-intro">
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path="/signin" component={{Signin}/>>
                        <Route path="/signup" component={{Signup}/>>
                        <this.PrivateRoute path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard}/>
                        <Route path="/admin/dashboard" component={AdminDashboard}/>
                        <Redirect to="/signin"/>
                    </Switch>
                    <div className="app-container">
                        <ReactNotification/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="App-footer">
                    <Football/>>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
}
```